# Cannot print pages in random order using lp/lpr

Tags: bash, printing, hplip, cups-lpd

Env: xfce4 + ubuntu + bash

Printer is configured by hplip.

```
lp -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 -o number-up=2 -o number-up-layout=lr -o page-ranges=320,289,321,300 ~/Documents/test.pdf 
lp: Bad page-ranges values 289-289.
```

The pdf file has more than 500 pages.
I want to incorporate a command in a script which can print random pages I select 2 pages on 1 side of an A4 sheet.

Comment: `320,289,321,300` try selecting pages to print in numerical order (`289,300,320,321`). It looks like `lp` cannot `seek` in a `.pdf`.

Comment: But I dont want to print in numnerical order. :)

Comment: Then, print in 3 `lp` commands - (320), (289,321) and (300). I repeat `lp` can't seek.

Comment: then it breaks another constraint I mentioned above. "print random pages I select 2 pages on 1 side of an A4 sheet"

Answer (score 1):

lp can't seek in a PDF, but pdftk can.  Try something like this:

```
pdftk test.pdf cat 320 289 321 300 output - | lp
```